# Add a post ID request at thumbnail shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

I use the following script to create a thumbnail shortcode, but this will only work at a loop or inside the post.

```
/* Thumb Shortcode */
function my_img() {
if (has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();  
    $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'medium');  
    $image_url = $image_url[0]; 
    $result = '<img src="'.$image_url.'" class="my_img" />';
    return $result;
}
return;
}
add_shortcode ('my_img', 'my_img');
```

Is there any simple way to modify it, so that I can use it everywhere with a post ID?

Like this:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[my_img post="100"]'); ?>
```

Comment: Try over at http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will use [`shortcode_atts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/shortcode_atts) to get the post shortcode attribute if it exist, if not it will use the thumb from the loop:

```
function my_img_func($atts) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
        'post' => null
    ), $atts, 'my_img');
    if($atts['post'] != null) {
        if (has_post_thumbnail((int) $atts['post']) ) {
            $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id((int) $atts['post']);  
            $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'medium');  
            $image_url = $image_url[0]; 
            $result = '<img src="'.$image_url.'" class="my_img" />';
            return $result;
        }
    } else {
        if (has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();  
            $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'medium');  
            $image_url = $image_url[0]; 
            $result = '<img src="'.$image_url.'" class="my_img" />';
            return $result;
        }
    }
    return '';
}
add_shortcode ('my_img', 'my_img_func');
```

Comment: Thx for support - so it will not work with "do_shortcode"? Because I try it like this <?php echo do_shortcode('[my_img post="100"]'); ?> and it doesn´t work.

Comment: `do_shortcode` just execute the shortcode, so yes it will work. You can do `echo do_shortcode('[my_img post="12"]');` in your template.

Comment: If it doesn't work can you do a `var_dump` of `$atts` at the start of the function?

Comment: Puh, I am really new at this - sry! What have I to do?

Comment: Just before `$atts = shortcode_atts` (the first line of the function), add `var_dump($atts);`. Reload your page, it should tell you the value of `$atts` so we'll see if your post ID get through the shortcode.

Comment: I´ve got this as result: array(1) { ["post"]=> string(3) "100" }

Comment: All right so it get the post id right. Just noticed that there was an error in the script - see updated.